# How to post multiple images to mastodon using api with bash curl

Tags: bash, api, rest, curl, mastodon

I'm starting to learn to use rest api via bash curl by writing a simple mastodon bot. I can attach multiple images using

```
curl https://example.com/api/v1/statuses \
                   -H 'Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN' \
                   -F "status=text" \
                   -F "media_ids[]=$id1" \
                   -F "media_ids[]=$id2" \
                   -F "media_ids[]=$id3"
```

But how to attach multiple pictures, when I don't know, how many filenames will be passed to the script? Documentation says, I should pass an array of ids. What is the right way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

To publish a new status with the previous uploaded image:

```bash
curl https://mastodon.social/api/v1/statuses -H 'Authorization: Bearer zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz' -F 'status=Here it is the rule 30 Cellular Automata!!' -F 'media_ids[]=109355507063219606'
```

Comment: Thanks! I was hitting a wall with that weird syntax for the `media_ids`.

Answer (score 0):

I handle to upload image to Mastodon this way:

```bash
$ curl -H "Authorization: Bearer zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz" -X POST -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" https://mastodon.social/api/v1/media --form file="@ca30.png"
```

it returns

```json
{"id":"109355507063219606","type":"image","url":"https://files.mastodon.social/media_attachments/files/109/355/507/063/219/606/original/007853b091c2d75e.png","preview_url":"https://files.mastodon.social/media_attachments/files/109/355/507/063/219/606/small/007853b091c2d75e.png","remote_url":null,"preview_remote_url":null,"text_url":null,"meta":{"original":{"width":200,"height":201,"size":"200x201","aspect":0.9950248756218906},"small":{"width":200,"height":201,"size":"200x201","aspect":0.9950248756218906}},"description":null,"blurhash":"U0KK==D%_3~q%M?bt7?b?bt7WBRj_3of4n4n"}
```